# Only aysnc methods lsited when call wcf

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8

I am trying to call a WCFService from Windows phone 8 which connects and returns data fine when i use WCFTestClient but when I refreence the service using add reference and then try to access in code only the async methods are showing in intelesence. I have not delciared my methods as aync how can i ensure I can access my other methods as I calling a webservice does it need be aysnc.

```
   // Constructor
public MainPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();

      IcuroServiceClient _db = new IcuroServiceClient();
        var json =_db.GetPersonByIdAsync(1);

}
```

And if so How would I convert a method that is as simple as below to Aysnc ?. I am used to asmx services and new to WCF.

```
    public string GetListByUserId(string userId)
    {

        List<curoList> myList = _db.GetAllListsByUserId(userId);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

        return json;

    }
```

[image]

Its grayed out here for me mate In my normal signature im returning a string but the asyncs dont look like their returning anything just void .
[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think in Windows Phone the preference is to use async.  Also, when adding a service async methods will/can be added by default (I believe it's a setting in the dialog box when adding).

Comment: @Tim ur on the ball tonight mate do you no the setting do you mean that they will be created automatic just its giving me that error void their as you see mate.

Comment: @Tim when me non asyc methods return me a string weird can anyone figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone is based literally and figuratively on the Silverlight motif of keeping all service calls async only. It is a two step process where one has to think backwards. Here are the steps

1. Provide a *callback* method whose job it is to handle the **resulting** data or error in an appropriate fashion.
2. Then make the call as one normally would (but calling the async version) to start the process off on a separate thread.

Be cognizant of not directly loading to the GUI in the callback method for the result is on a different thread; note that loading to VM properties is fine for the most part whereas the update to any GUI subscribed bindings will be done on the thread.

---

### Hot to Resolve

In the example given before the call to to `db.GetPersonByIdAsync(1)` provide (find using intellisense) the async subscription method that has the call back.

It may be prefixed with either a `Load` method or a `Begin` call, for the `PersonById`.

In the editor, the providing of a method is usually done by intellisense which where one can *tab* an example into code. That is so one doesn't have to root out the parameters for the callback method.

Possible example, shows the how to do it:

```
client.GetPersonByIdAsyncCompleted += MyMethodToHandleResultforGetPerson;   // var personId = e.Result;
client.GetPersonByIdAsync(1);
```

---

### Why

When Silverlight was designed, having a program wait (even if its busy waiting) on any thread would slow down the browser experience. By requiring all database (service) calls to be asynchronous ensures that the developer can't slow down the browser, in particular by *bad code*. Loosely speaking that motif carried over to the windows phone where Silverlight was brought over as the main operations for the phone.

It took me awhile to get used to the process, but now that I have worked on Silverlight and Windows phone, I actually use the async motif in WPF even though I don't necessarily have too, it makes sense in terms of data processing and thread management.

It is not easier for the developer per-se for everyone learns in a synchronous *hello world*, but it is adapted for the needs of the target platform and once learned it becomes second nature.

Comment: can you please demostrate an example for me as I dont no cause my retrun type of my normal methods are string when i add them into the silverlight it generates the async methods thanks for ur response.

Comment: @Murphy There are different flavors of async, so can you list the different methods intellisense provides for any `PersonById` and I can step you through it.

Comment: but i do not understand how to overide the voide so i can return a string?

Comment: @Murphy The callback gets the return value from a specialized argument. That argument also has whether the operation succeeded or not. If it succeeded one extracts the value. If you could post the other methods of `xxxPersonByID` provided by the context I could show you.

Comment: its in the same format as above dont want to release to much code on here